# Make Redmine fully multi-lingual?

Tags: plugins, translation, redmine, multilingual

We're currently facing a little problem with our redmine, that I didn't think I'd could become one.

Redmine has multi-language support for all the built-in features and texts, but it lacks a possibility to offer translations for custom fields and user created texts like issue-trackers and such.
We started a German support system based on Redmine and would now like to share the information stored with our British colleagues. We have no problem with translating the necessary wiki pages, nor typing in the tickets from abroad in English, but as we use some custom fields they will always be shown in German and we currently see no way around this.

Is anyone here already happy with a solution for this? Any plugins availabe that I don't know of? I know of Localizable (http://www.redmine.org/plugins/localizable), but I've heard of Redmine 2.5 users having trouble with this one and I don't want to risk any plugin to mess with my system.